# In what way can I increase the likelihood of miscarriages across a species?

Tags: biology, society

Exowombs have become feasible from a technological standpoint. A number of trials conducted on animal embryos have proven successful, and talk has been made about how this can be beneficial for humanity. Talk has been floating around on how this technology can benefit humanity, and whether it should be mass produced.

However, smooth introduction of this technology will not be as simple as that.  Abortion is a hot topic, and will always be, even without the religious aspect. Any tests revolving around artificial wombs would essentially be experiements. These exowombs would require thousands of human embryos for early trials. Disregarding renegade actors, no ethics board will likely condone this. There are so many risks, medically and morally, that people would riot in the streets and many politicians would avoid touching it with a ten foot pole.

To fast-track this, there needs to be some shift in childbirth rates that affected us as a species. This would force artificial wombs to become the only solution. Leaders would introduce it as a necessary evil at first. As time goes on, it would become normalized in society.

To accomplish this, I need to design this concept around a crisis that raises the possibility of miscarriages, to the point where a child surviving normal childbirth would be rare. This would affect the developing child specifically, instead of the parent dying. At first, I considered some kind of virus or plague. The problem is that this would likely mutate into something that kills large amounts of people, which is not what I want.

Hoe can I make this possible?

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is something like Zika virus. Doesn't cause miscarriage, does cause serious and irreparable developmental issues.

Comment: Miscarriages are, unfortunately, quite common.  It's a relatively high risk for older mothers, so I really don't think the issue is the hot potato you think it is, at least not everywhere.  I think finding mere "thousands" who would want to try it is not likely to be a legal or moral issue widespread enough to prevent it happening.

Comment: Aside from the moral circular loop of logic you have in which you induce embryo death to shift embryos to artificial wombs to save them later, why can't you just perfect the process off of chimp fetuses, and then use the artificial wombs against extreme cases in human to prove it works?

Comment: Human embryos are not that hard to come by; the in-vitro fertilization industry has a surfeit of fertilized eggs. Thousands of human embryos are *already being used* (and, obviously, destroyed) annually for [human embryonic stem cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryonic_stem_cell) research. Not all countries on this Earth share the American view that [every sperm is sacred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Every_Sperm_Is_Sacred). The point being that unless for some mysterious reason the research *must* take place in the U.S.A. there is really no problem to acquire the needed embryos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History does not support your assertion that tests of this kind would lead to rioting in the streets.  There is a pretty good analogue in recent history for this event; the invention of IVF.

Louise Brown was the first "test tube baby," born July 25, 1978.  At the time, no one knew if it would work in humans or if the resulting baby would have abnormalities.  It was an experiment, just as your exo-womb trials would be.  Edwards and Steptoe, the scientists working on the treatment, were rejected for public grants and had to seek private funding. There was *some* controversy at the time; newspapers predicted "all hell would break loose" and the Catholic church condemned the practice.   The Brown family received a few death threats.  But there weren't any riots and a year later IVF was widely accepted and the same newspapers poked fun at their earlier panic in year-in-review sections.  All it took was one baby born healthy for the panic to dissipate.

The pressure from infertile couples seeking new treatments far outweighed the few who had nebulous objections to IVF.  In the case of exo-wombs, I imagine the pressure from all sorts of people seeking to shed the burdens and dangers of pregnancy would be even more overwhelming. You're probably right that politicians wouldn't want any part of it, so the pioneers of this technology would probably have to be privately funded, which means starting small; a handful of pregnancies or perhaps a single one to start.  Once it is shown to work in the initial cases, the public backlash should be largely deflated.  I don't think there would be a shortage of volunteers.  Roughly 1 in 5 recognized pregnancies end in miscarriage.  Roughly 1 in 10 women ages 15-44 have trouble getting and staying pregnant.  More than 1% of pregnancies will end with the death of the mother. 
 You don't need to inflate those numbers.  Many people in our world, especially those who have experienced one or more miscarriages, would jump at the chance to outsource their pregnancies if it meant a greater chance of safely carrying to term.

Sources:

https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/06/the-ivf-panic-all-hell-will-break-loose-politically-and-morally-all-over-the-world/258954/

https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/vitro-fertilization-was-once-controversial-cloning-today-180964989/

Answer (score 5):

**Miscarriage**

There are several factors that could increase the risk of miscarriage,

- Highly increased/decreased blood pressure
- Lower blood oxygen content
- Genetic
- Infection

The list goes on, all can have an effect on viability of the fetus to a lesser or greater extent, and i think what causes the chosen effect would probably come under the "Too Broad" heading, but could be anything from a planet wide virus/bacteria, increased solar radiation, poor diet or [insert generic doomsday scenario dialed down to survivable]

But the fundamental question your asking is actually how to encourage the fast tracking of the Exowomb to make it commonplace.

**Sterility**

Using the same reasons above why not make humans not quiet sterile but far less capable of natural procreation, like pandas. with a global birth rate shrinking but couples still wanting children then the Exowomb gives them the best option, taking healthy eggs and healthy sperms and having them get to know each other in a local hotspot... the test tube.

This would mean couples can have kids when otherwise the likelihood of conception would be very low.

**Risk not to the child, but to the mother**

If for [insert doomsday type] reasons, the risk of carrying a baby full term meant a significantly higher risk to the mother dying, then people would still want children but not want to risk the mothers life, therefore the Exowomb would offer them the chance of children but without the risk. which coincidentally leads me onto my final idea

**Vanity**

"Don't have dessert... have a Cigarette" was a genuine marketing campaign for cigarette companies in the 30s, it was aimed around dieting and women wanting to not gain weight. so simply having the market slogan aim for the same reasons might have a significant effect at least on the non religious...

*Worried about putting on baby weight? ankles swelling up? the effect it will have on your intimate life with your partner? why put your body through all that when Exowomb can do it all for you?*

Marketing done right is very effective (above probably isn't right, i'm not a marketing guy) so the Exowomb company would definitely want to to encourage people to do use it, and this wouldn't need some doomsday cause, just heartless corporate entities... like that would ever happen. *but don't forget the stupidity of people! calling it iExowomb would be far more effective then Exowomb!*

**Disclaimer: I do not mean any of these things against pregnant women! i'm just trying to impersonate stupid marketing campaigns!!!!!!**

In your world, probably a combination of the above would be effective

Answer (score 1):

[Brucellosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brucellosis) can cause spontaneous abortions in cattle. It is also transmissible to humans. Modern health care has drastically reduced the incidence in cows, and pasteurization reduces that passing to humans.

Chillingly, it was [weaponized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brucellosis#Biological_warfare), the program discontinued by President Nixon.

So, surmise a bio-warfare program. A strain of Brucellosis is created that causes abortions in humans. Surmise that it has been deliberately given resistance to the usual anti-bacterial measures, because it is after all a weapon.
And it is released, either by accident or deliberately. It may not be immediately recognized what is happening since the illness is not drastically different from many more prosaic illnesses. And the government responsible for the release may be hiding the fact, either because they don't want to be blamed or because they are evil.

After some time it is recognized that some disease is loose and that nearly every pregnant woman who gets it will lose the baby. High emotions follow, with a lot of effort to do something about this right *now*. Maybe attempts at a vaccine are not immediately successful. And maybe those who have had the disease now find they are permanently at risk of miscarriage.

Answer (score 1):

Man made environmental factors often take decades to identify properly, and decades more to legislate away.  For your scenario, you just need to take something most people will assume is safe, but is far more harmful to embryos than adults, and put it everywhere.

One such example is ultrasound.  People assume it is safer than radiation; so, the government starts putting AI monitored ultrasound devices all over the place to detect for concealed weapons, drug trafficking, etc.  In reality, there are stages during fetal development where ultrasound interferes with the formation of certain neurological structures causing severe brain deformations.  In near future dystopian police state, pregnant women who routinely go shopping, or out to public parks, or through the front door at work are scanned several times a day leading to a massive uptake in neurological development issues.

Test-tube babies don't have this problem.  They sit in a lab away from all the ultra sound devices leading to a much higher healthy birth rate.  Because these ultrasound devices are so integral to your government for maintaining control, politicians go to absurd measures to deny the harmfulness of ultrasound scanners.  They scapegoat everything else they can think of like global warming, radiation, cell phones, smoking, etc, etc, etc.  So many things get blamed for it that no actual legislation is written to ban any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Some plants have abortive substances in them. Also every woman seems to be immune to some plants, with the immunity varying by genetic factors and/or acquired resistance.

Boldo, cinammon and seringa bark teas may induce premature labor or abortion in some women. Just have some concentration of the active effects in staple foods and the water supply and you get the effect you want - overall fertility in the population will seem to go down, while still keeping a good portion of pregnancies viable.

Answer (score 0):

A virus that affects the uterus.

Say a virus has spread that makes the lining of the uterus unable to accept a zygote or forces it to spontaneously miscarry at some point during pregnancy. The virus is cosmopolitan and everywhere, and no vaccine exists. It causes no outward symptoms, and nearly everyone is infected by it by age 4.

The virus doesn't affect ovulation, so for reproduction, a couple goes to a fertility clinic, which extracts gametes and fertilizes the embryo under lab conditions. The embryos are then optionally screened for disease or traits.

You could even use this as an extra plot device, say that culturally over time this has lead to changes in the population, whether it be skin color, gender, eye color, intelligence, etc., the necessity of lab fertilization has created an entire culture of designer babies.